# What is the reasoning for having such prior distribution function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bayesian

For the following problem, what is the reasoning for having such prior distribution function $f_\Theta(\theta)$?  If the random variable of interest $\Theta$ is the time of arrival $\theta$, I am inclined to think that $f_\Theta(\theta) = \theta$ for $0\leq\theta\leq 1$ and $f_\Theta(\theta) = 0$ otherwise.  Can someone explain to me?

[image: ro]

Comment: Do you understand that what they wrote down for the pdf for $\Theta$ is the pdf of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$? I'm not sure why you think prior distribution should be $f(\theta)=\theta$ instead... it's a prior distribution... it's an assumption... there is no right or wrong answer per se for what it "should" be in a toy problem. (Also note that $f(\theta)=\theta,$ $0<\theta<1$ is not even a normalized pdf, though it would be if you multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I misunderstood $f_\Theta(\theta)$, which is the PDF of the value $\theta$.  I thought it stood for the value of $\theta$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Which prior is "uninformative" (i.e., treats each  value of $\theta$ equally)?

[image]

Because the OP seems unfamiliar with this concept, let me write a few words about the value of uninformative priors.

Suppose you choose a non-uniform prior over $\theta$, say one that makes it a higher probability for $\theta = 7$ than $\theta = 3$.  What prior information do you have to assert such a case?  *Why* is $7$ more likely than $3$ (before any data has been taken)?  Suppose you somehow want to believe that $7$ is more likely than $3$ and someone else says "no... I think that $3$ is more likely than $7$."  Who is right?  How can you tell (before data is selected)?

The *unique* prior that treats all values equally is the uniform prior (here, a constant as a function of $\theta$).

The same process occurs with discrete distributions, of course.  If someone gives you a six-sided die (which *might* be unbalanced), you don't know *how* it is unbalanced, i.e., which number is more likely to come up.  If you magically (and with no evidence) think that $2$ is more likely to arise than $4$ (for instance), but someone else says the reverse, how could you *ever* demonstrate who is right (before you roll the die)?  You cannot.

If you still don't understand this foundational idea in Bayesian reasoning, I urge you to look online on read any number of books on the subject, including my ***Pattern classification*** (2nd ed.) by Duda, Hart and Stork.

Comment: Should priors be uninformative?  I don't quite follow.

Comment: @J.Doe The prior is the distribution you initially believe the parameter follows. If you have very little knowledge of the what the parameter is initially then your prior should reflect that by having a wide distribution. The uniform distribution seems like a natural choice to express that you have no foreknowledge of the parameter. However there are a couple alternatives with good arguments for them as well, like the Haldane and Jeffreys priors, both of which diverge near 0 and 1.

Comment: By the same token it’s not trivial to say $f(\theta) =2\theta$ is a particularly informative prior (though no one would seriously argue it is a good candidate for the default uninformative prior). If our parameter was $\Theta^2$ rather than theta, then this prior would be the uniform distribution.

Comment: Actually (and sorry for continuing to nitpick here), re-reading the problem, there is nothing telling us that $\theta$ needs to be between $0$ and $1,$ only that it is positive. So a U(0,1) distribution is actually *quite* informative, and not a natural choice at all! The conventional uninformative prior here would be the improper prior $1/\theta$ for $\theta>0.$ (I had forgotten the original problem and just assumed that we were doing inference for a bernoulli parameter in the comments above.)

Comment: You give no justification whatsoever for the improper prior.  (Being improper is itself a drawback... that's why it is called "IMproper.")  And nobody said $\theta$ is between $0$ and $1$...  I think you have a lot of basic misunderstandings, and I don't have more time to go through them.  Over and out.

Comment: No, I really don't. And someone did say the prior for $\theta$ is uniform between 0 and 1... the original question said that. And if we aren't making that restriction and $\theta$ has an unbounded uniform prior, then that is an even more improper prior than $1/\theta$... at least that decays, even if its integral doesn't converge. The reason I say log-uniformity rather than uniformity is the standard choice is cause that's the usual for a scale parameter (e.g. it's what's typically taught for the standard deviation)...

Comment: https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/Bayesian/Handouts/Ch4Priors.pdf (It is the Jeffreys prior in this case too: $\frac{\partial^2 \log f(x\mid\theta)}{\partial\theta^2} = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$).